# Media query issue with HTC One Mini native browser

Tags: android, html, css

Generally the media queries set in the CSS are recognized by the browser I can't tell why, beacuse I have put the correct meta tags. And it is working on every other browser (Chrome, Opera, Firefox...). Except the native browser.

Meta tags:

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

The media queries that are set for mobile devices are:

```
@media screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 667px){}

@media screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 667px) and (orientation : portrait) {}

@media screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 667px) and (orientation:landscape){}
```

Answer (score 0):

The @media is a less-used tag and you should avoid using it, only a few browsers support it and major mobile browsers like Safari, UC do not.. So try to write your code in some other way ... Consider this link - http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-your-HTML-Website-suitable-for-Mobile-Devices/
 @media is anyways a tag not supported by most of the browsers since the modern devices consider them to be high resolution and not ones which require @media tags like handheld or custom settings.. @media is suitable only for purposes like printing..

Comment: it's also one of the most widely used tags in responsive web design.

Answer (score 0):

The `viewport` meta tag is repeated twice in you html which is not correct. Also the tag has redundant attributes, using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

should give the same result. More on [viewports meta tag](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/).

Comment: Yeah, read the article, it didn't help that much, still having the same issue. Do you have any other advice? Thank in advance.

Comment: I don't see any error in your CSS syntax. Is the browser using the default view settings? Clean app data and try again. Also some screenshots would be nice.